# Azure Lighthouse - Call HTTP endpoint once everything is deployed

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to onboard a subscription into my tenant and once it's finished, I want to call an HTTP endpoint, to process some other logic on my side.

Since my ARM template executes on the subscription scope, I cannot use [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template), as it requires a resource group.
The other workaround I found, is to use a [deployment that gets the template from a URL](https://blog.cloudtrooper.net/2017/04/04/run-azure-functions-from-your-quickstart-arm-templates/). But, there is a problem with this as well. In my case, the endpoint gets called three times, even though I set the `dependsOn` parameter.
It gets called:

1. Once validated
2. Once the deployment is initialized
3. Once all other resources are deployed.

Here's some part of the ARM template:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    // Other properties
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('mspRegistrationName')]",
            "properties": {
                "registrationDefinitionName": "[parameters('mspOfferName')]",
                "description": "[parameters('mspOfferDescription')]",
                "managedByTenantId": "[variables('managedByTenantId')]",
                "authorizations": "[variables('authorizations')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "name": "[variables('mspAssignmentName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "registrationDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Callback",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "location": "westus",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[variables('TemplateUri')]"
                },
                "parameters":  {}
            }
        }
    ],
```

Of course, I can hardcode that the third call is valid, but that's not a good approach.
Is there any "safer" way of calling the endpoint from ARM template?

Comment: Is there a policy or rule prohibiting you from creating a resource group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a resource group with the ARM template, then deploy a nested template containing a deployment script into it. Both RGs and RG-level deployments can be created as resources in a subscription-level template.

An alternative would be to create an Azure function with an event grid trigger, listening for [ARM events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-subscriptions?tabs=event-grid-event-schema), though this would also require resources that can only be deployed at the resource group level.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I think the events are what I look for. Got one question if you don't mind. I've got a Service bus on user 1 account. Using the ARM template (Lighthouse) I want to create an event subscription that will send messages to the service bus on user 1. Is there a way to achieve such cross-account messaging?

Comment: This would be possible so long as both subscriptions exist in the same AAD tenant. You would grant write permissions on the service bus (in account 1) to the event grid (in account 2). You can learn more about how you would do this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization